# The carpenter repaired SOME legs of the tables

Tags: some-vs-any

My question was engendered by this question
[Which is correct, "The carpenter repaired the legs of the tables" or "The carpenter repaired legs of the tables"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/86579/which-is-correct-the-carpenter-repaired-the-legs-of-the-tables-or-the-carpen)

I wonder what this means: The carpenter repaired **SOME legs of the tables**.

> 1. Some legs of all the legs which were there
> 2. Some legs of the broken legs **only**
> 3. Either 2 or 3

There were 16 legs in total. 8 were broken. Some were repaired. Does that mean 1) all 8 were repaired or 2) Fewer than 8

Comment: I don't think this is a thing that anyone would ever say.

Comment: Exactly the same sentence or the construction "some + noun of the + noun"?

Comment: Something can be grammatically correct without being idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### It's ambiguous, but probably doesn't mean "all of them".

"Some of the legs were repaired" means that some proportion of the legs were repaired; this could be some proportion of all of the legs (thus potentially repairing all of the broken legs), or some proportion of the broken legs (likely leaving some of them unrepaired).

If you want to tell which one the sentence means, you need to discern it from context.